# Is it acceptable to rewrite methods in a dependent class to avoid get().get().get() code?

Tags: java

I wrote my own Point(int x, int y) and Circle (Point center, int radius) classes to brush up on class relations and some basic maths.

If I want to draw a Circle to screen, my current code looks something like the following:

```
g.drawOval(circle.getCenter().getX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getCenter().getY() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getRadius()*2, circle.getRadius()*2);
```

Is it acceptable to simply write methods in my Circle class that pass the fields of its Point in my main class / applet?

```
    g.drawOval(circle.getX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getY() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getRadius()*2, circle.getRadius()*2);
```

My concern is that, when I start creating more concrete objects (Such as a Player class), I'll end up with code where a single field being passed through layers results in a huge amount of text.

```
int x = player.getCircle().getPoint().getX();
```

instead of

```
int x = player.getX();
```

It seems to me that the beauty of Java is writing classes once to handle whatever needs you have, and letting them handle all the overhead. It's useful to me to learn how other people handle this kind of stuff, which is why I try to find lots of etiquette, formatting, and standards guidelines.

I want my code to be transparent, as well - would it be immediately apparent to another coder that the last line of code is fetching an int through a series of dependencies?

This question might elicit a lot of different opinions, which is fine for me - but I feel like there might be a particular standard that is popular amongst most Java coders.

Comment: *Be immediately apparent to another coder that the last line of code is fetching an `int` through a series of dependencies.* Why? Other coders don't need to know your implementation.

Comment: Emphasizing (or somehow "justifying") the comment by johnchen902: You should also think about whether the `Player` class should have a `getCircle()` method at all. Maybe, later there will be a `Rectangle` stored in the `Player`. Then, `getX()` may still make sense, whereas `getCircle()` will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define methods for accessing properties of internal objects :

```
class Circle {
   int getX () {
       int x = -1;
       if (getCenter() != null)
           x = getCenter().getX();
       return x;
   }
}

class Player {
   int getX () {
       int x = -1;
       if (getCircle() != null)
           x = getCircle().getX();
       return x;
   }
}
```

Introducing these methods has the advantage of not having to put all the null checks in the code that uses the outer class (Player in your example), since the `player.getCircle().getPoint().getX()` should be replaced with this safer code, to avoid NullPointerExceptions :

```
if (player != null)
    if (player.getCircle() != null)
        if (player.getCircle().getPoint() != null)
            x = player.getCircle().getPoint().getX();
```

Of course, this ugly code can also be avoided by using Java 8 Optionals.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not only acceptable but desirable in cases like yours.

A class represents some object in your domain; a method is a way of doing something with that object.  A method that obtains the X coordinate of the center of a Circle object should not reveal how that is stored within the Circle class; you reveal that if the way to do that is to obtain an internal object from which you get the coordinate.

The important part is that the method represent an operation on the object itself; you wouldn't want to do this *just* to bypass an internal representation, i.e., not just because the code will work, but because the method you are writing reflects a natural operation on the class on which it is called.